# Get extension std::out_of_range error

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this piece of code? Is there another way to do this?
It keeps throwing std::out_of_range error.

```
std::wstring ext(FileInformation.cFileName);
ext = ext.substr(ext.find(L"."));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is that you are not handling the case that the file has no extension.

What happens is that [`ext.find(L".")` returns `std::wstring::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/find/#return) (the highest possible number - indicating "not found") because it doesn't find a dot.

You are then calling `ext.substr(std::wstring::npos)` which is of course out of range.

You have to check for this case:

```
std::wstring ext(FileInformation.cFileName);
std::size_t dotPos = ext.find(L".");
if(dotPos != std::wstring::npos) {
    ext = ext.substr(dotPos);
} else {
    ext = L"."; // assuming you want to treat an empty extension like this
}
```

However, if your goal is to extract the file extension, there are some more gotchas you need to be aware of:

- Windows considers only the part after the last dot as the file extension. Your code will give `.a.b` for a file named `file.a.b` while Windows will consider the file extension to be just `.b`. So you probably need to use `rfind` instead of `find`, which searches backwards.
- But then there is another subtlety: A file extension can't contain a space (`file.hello world` is a file without extension), so you would need to check this as well...

Therefore, since you are obviously already using WinAPI, I'd advise you to use the WinAPI function made for exactly this purpose: [`PathFindExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587(v=vs.85).aspx). This way, you can't get it wrong.

Example (assuming you still want a dot - remove it otherwise):

```
ext = std::wstring(L".") + *PathFindExtension(ext.c_str());
```

Alternatively, there would also be the `boost` library which also has a way to extract the file extension using [`boost::path::extension`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-extension), but it's kinda heavy and if you don't already use `boost`, it's not worth considering it.

Comment: I don't understand why we have to keep teaching people to _check for errors_ when they do things. Is it not an intuitive thing to have to do? If you try to find something in a string why would you not expect to have to handle the case where that something isn't found? Boggles the mind.

Answer (score 1):

There can be no "." in `FileInformation.cFileName` and `find` will return `std::wstring::npos` so first check the return of `find` and then call `substr`.

Maybe something like this:

```
std::wstring ext(FileInformation.cFileName);
std::size_t found=ext.find(L".");
if (found!=std::wstring::npos)
    ext = ext.substr(found);
```

Answer (score 1):

FileInformation.cFileName did not include a dot then find() will return string::npos.

So you need to check for string::npos at first befor using substr cause if first argument to substr is greater than the string length, it throws out_of_range.